# Promise in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write a synchronous function call in Angular using a Promise, but it still gets a different result than expected.
I have 2 functions that use the service that download data from the API:

```
getData1(shortcut: string): void {
  this.apiServ.getPrice(shortcut).subscribe(
    (price: CurrentPrice) => {
      this.price = price;
      console.log(1);
    },
    error => this.error = error
  );
}

getData2(shortcut: string): void {
  this.apiServ.getPrice(shortcut).subscribe(
    (price: CurrentPrice) => {
      this.price = price;
      console.log(2);
    },
    error => this.error = error
  );
}
```

I'm trying to make the next function call after the response is completed. So:

```
data(shortcuts) {
  this.getData1(shortcuts[0]);
  this.getData2(shortcuts[1]);
}

ngOnInit() {
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.data(this.shortcuts);
    resolve(3)
  });
  myPromise.then((value) => {console.log(value)});
}
```

But my browser prints this call order:

```
3 
1 
2
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I also tried to use callbacks but the effect is always the same.

Comment: Why both are assigning value to `this.price = price;` ??? is this a typo ?

Comment: Do you want to use Promise only or can we use observables to do it?

Comment: You're resolving promise immediately without waiting async functions to complete. The promise wrapper doesn't make them synchronous

Comment: What sequence are you expecting if not `3,1,2` ?

Comment: 1. In fact, I added to the table, I wanted the example to be as simple as possible. 2. I expected that then() segment be at the end @bjdose Prefer Promise.

Comment: @AlekseyL. So what condition can I use to resolve my promise  after the response is complete?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use promises you can use *async/await* but instead you can use rxjs for doing this.

**Observable flow**

I create two functions to simulate your problem, one is called getDataAsObservable which represents your getData method, and another one called getDataAsPromise which represents your promise, then I use the concat that is an observable creation method from rxjs which sequentially emits all values from given Observable and then moves on to the next.

I pass first$, second$, and third$ asynchronous functions to concat and to subscribe in order to print the result out.

**Promise flow**

Otherwise, if you use *async/await*, you only need to wait for the response.

```js
  import { Observable, concat } from 'rxjs';
  import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';


  async ngOnInit() {
    // first execute promise flow and wait for the response
    await this.executePromiseFlow();
    // after promise flow we can execute observable flow
    this.executeObservableFlow(); 
  }

  executePromiseFlow = async () => {
    // I use toPromise method to convert observable to a promise
    const first = await this.getDataAsObservable(1).toPromise();
    console.info('[Promise] output', first);
    const second = await this.getDataAsObservable(2).toPromise();
    console.info('[Promise] output', second);
    const third = await this.getDataAsPromise(3);
    console.info('[Promise] output', third);
  }

  executeObservableFlow = () => {
    const second$ = this.getDataAsObservable(2);
    const first$ = this.getDataAsObservable(1);
    const third$ = this.getDataAsPromise(3);

    concat(first$, second$, third$)
      .subscribe((output) => console.info('[Observable] output', output))
  }

  getDataAsObservable = (value: number) => { 
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(value);
      observer.complete();
    }).pipe(
      delay(value * 2000), // simulate HTTP request time
    );
  }

  getDataAsPromise = (value: number) => {  
    return Promise.resolve(value);
  }
```

You can read more about async/await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and rxjs [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/).

You can check a simple reproduction of this [here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfjgoe)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip` from rxjs:

import { Observable, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

```
getData1(shortcut: string): Observable<any>  {
  return this.apiServ.getPrice(shortcut).pipe(
    tap(
      (price: CurrentPrice) => {
        this.price = price;
        console.log(1);
      }
    )
  );
}

getData2(shortcut: string): Observable<any>  {
  return this.apiServ.getPrice(shortcut).pipe(
    tap(
      (price: CurrentPrice) => {
        this.price = price;
        console.log(2);
      }
    )
  );
}


data(shortcuts) : Observable<any> {
  const res1 = this.getData1(shortcuts[0]);
  const res2 = this.getData2(shortcuts[1]);
  return zip(res1, res2);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data(this.shortcuts).subscribe(() => {
    // your code
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because they are promises you need to respect their resolve time, it means to wait until they are completed and that means you can't call them as a normal function when you rely on their result.

Also because it's an angular app try to convert them to rxjs stream via `from` function.

```js
getData1(shortcut: string): Observable<CurrentPrice> { // <- return stream
  return this.apiServ.getPrice(shortcut).pipe(
    tap(console.log, console.log), // logs emits and errors
  );
}

getData2(shortcut: string): Observable<CurrentPrice> { // <- return stream
  return this.apiServ.getPrice(shortcut).pipe(
    tap(console.log, console.log), // logs emits and errors
  );
}

data(shortcuts): Observable<[CurrentPrice, CurrentPrice]> { // <- return stream
  return combineLatest([
    this.getData1(shortcuts[0]),
    this.getData2(shortcuts[1]),
  ]);
}

ngOnInit() {
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, error) => {
    // wait until completed
    this.data(this.shortcuts).pipe(
      take(1), // <- in promise we need just 1 emit
    ).subscribe(prices => resolve(prices), error); 
  });
  myPromise.then((value) => {console.log(value)}); // profit
}
```